# jquery validate not working with two forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form where a enter a card number and from that number i get info from a table, and before submitting the other form  I want to validate the account_number. But its not working, it ignores the validate, but when I get rid of the first form  the validate works fine.

I'm using the first form to get data from a table.

Made a https://jsfiddle.net/vwvefrt8/

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
alert('test');
  var validator = $('#searchForm').validate({

    rules: {
      info_test: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {},


    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('change','input',function(){
$(this).valid();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You failed to include jQuery in your jsFiddle.  You also failed to include the jQuery Validate plugin.  Pay attention to the console errors.

Comment: oh sorry since i have coldfsion stuff , my thought was that it wouldnt matter since in jsfiddle it wont work

Comment: Where do you mention Coldfusion in your OP, and why would you construct a jsFiddle demo showing us server-side code that "won't work"?  If you need help with JavaScript, then construct a *working* demo using only the rendered HTML and any required JavaScript assets.

Answer (score 0):

As per JavaScript console errors in [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwvefrt8/)...

1. You failed to include jQuery and the jQuery Validate plugin.
2. You have `data-error="##errNm3"` on `info_test` and the `#` character is breaking your JavaScript in the custom `errorPlacement` function.

> *"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##errNm3"*

As well as...

3. You are missing the closing `</table>` tag in your first `table` which is breaking the HTML.  The jQuery Validate plugin does not always work well with broken HTML structure when it affects how the `<form></form>` tags are nested.

Otherwise, it's working:  https://jsfiddle.net/1kf6th4L/

---

In the comments section, you mention that the code in the jsFiddle is from Coldfusion.  Since you're only showing us the server-side code, rather than the actual HTML markup that's being rendered in the browser, item #2 might be a moot point.  Regardless, since this was posted as a JavaScript issue with no mention of Coldfusion, we would need to see the same code that the JavaScript engine in the browser would see.

Comment: but the data-error="##errNm3" i use because its needed because of coldfusion, i have use this in other forms and works fine with two ##

Comment: @anatp_123 - look at your JavaScript console:  *"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##errNm3"*

Comment: yes thats truth but on my side I get no error on my console, since im using coldfusion its different, i have other forms and works fine those forms do only have 1 form

Comment: @anatp_123, you posted a question with a broken jsFiddle and I fixed it.  You mentioned nothing about Coldfusion.  JavaScript in the user's browser also does not care about Coldfusion... the `#` character is breaking it, period.

Comment: it may be breaking it in the jsfiddle but not my code, i have other forms that i use the same javascript and no error works fine

Comment: @anatp_123, do you even need the `#` characters in that attribute?  Is this what you're really wanting to do?  https://jsfiddle.net/1kf6th4L/1/

Comment: @anatp_123, again, I can only help you with what you're showing us.   When seeking help with JavaScript issues, it's best to only show us the ***RENDERED*** HTML output... not your Coldfusion server-side code.